# Visual Studio 2015 can compile and run but I can't find .exe in both Release/ and Debug/

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Today I code as usual. Everything seems to go well in Visual Studio 2015. It can compile and run the program successfully in VS2015. However, when I go to the `Debug/` dir, I can't find `.exe` file, all I can see are below:

[image]

It seems that the VS2015 can't link these `.obj` to create a `.exe` file, while I have no idea how to fix it. Is there anyone who can help? Thx in advance.

Comment: open cmd.exe, go to the directory where the .sln file resists and try this `dir /s *.exe`.

Comment: *"run the program successfully"* this implies that files are linked properly. To figure out where .exe is located run the program, open Tasks manager and check properties of corresponding process.

Comment: `.exe` file must be generated in a different directory then.

Comment: check project settings..it's quite possible that project is set to build .exe file in directory outside of source tree

Comment: All the way above can work. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should right click on your main Visual C++ project in Visual Studio, select Properties, and check the Output Directory property on the General page. Also don't forget to check your build configuration and platform (e.g. Debug, x64) on the top of the settings page, as by the default settings those affect the output directory.

[Visual C++ Project Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Uyu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The exe is in a different "debug" folder, that is in the parent folder.

As in, when I right-click on the project in visual studio and select "show in folder", it opens source\repos<projectname><projectname> and in there is the .cpp file and a debug folder. But this is not the debug folder you are looking for.

Go to up a folder to sources\repos<projectname> theres another debug folder there that contains the exe